# Phoneticised alphabet letters

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, alphabet, letter-names

Do all letters of the English alphabet have phoneticised dictionary entries? I'm thinking of the word Vee for the letter V or Zed for the letter Z? For example is there an entry for H? Aitch?

Comment: There are no standard spellings for the alphabet letters. They are their own standard, and they appear first in each alphabetic list. There are lot of unofficial eye spellings like _vee_ or _zed_, but they're nonce forms.

Comment: Those spelled-out letters are very important for the game Scrabble.  Two-letter words like *ef* and *ar*, for example.  Yes, *aitch* is found in enough dictionaries to be allowed in Scrabble.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As John Lawler and GEdgar note, there is no universally agreed-upon spelling for every letter. Some initialisms have been lexicalized and  that may influence what is recognized as a phonetic spelling, e.g. *emcee* or *deejay*, but consider also that letters may be pronounced differently by different people, e.g. *zed* vs. *zee*, *aitch* vs. *haitch*.

Comment: @JohnLawler "nonce" is not a synonym for "unofficial". Letter spellings are used in multiple places, and thus are not nonce.

Comment: @Accumulation Yes, that I was getting at in my question. "Vee" has its own dictionary entry, used to describe anything "V" shaped.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> There are no standard spellings for the alphabet letters. They are their own standard, and they appear first in each alphabetic list. There are lot of unofficial eye spellings like *vee* or *zed*, but they're nonce forms.