# Is there a specific term for those words that are phoneticised letters of the English alphabet?

Tags: single-word-requests, phonetics

This post [Phoneticised alphabet letters](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482665/phoneticised-alphabet-letters) refers to "initialisms," a term that describes a word that has been formed by phoneticizing a set of initials that is in common usage, such as "emcee" or "deejay."

Is there an analogous term for those words that are formed by phoneticizing the names of the letters of the alphabet, such as "aitch" or "vee?"

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63641/163776